# Generates a signed JSON Web Token using a Google API Service Account in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform

I have express/nodejs api that communication with our java backend services (not google API's). I need pass a google JWT token to the api calls.

How do I Generates a signed JSON Web Token using a Google API Service Account. Most of example I  see get an access-token or refresh.

Thanks for your help

Comment: 1) Using what tool/library do you want to use to create a JWT. A JWT is simply two JSON objects concatenated together with a signature. 2) For what purpose will you be using the JWT? (backend service is not detailed enough) That will determine what kind of JWT to create. 3) Most Google APIs do not accept JWTs and require OAuth Access Tokens or OIDC Identity Tokens. If the backend is performing its own token validation, you can use anything your backend supports. 4) Edit your question with details, your generalized description is not enough to create a solid and secure answer.

Comment: Agree with John comment. In addition, what is generating the token? And where? ON GCP, on yyour workstation? Elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [JSON Web Tokens](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#json-web-tokens).

Comment: Thanks,, but I don't see where any of the example produce a JWT token.. They all generate an access or refresh token

Comment: You're right. My apologies. I just had the same issue. It's a JWT but the `access_token` contains a value beginning `ya29` token (right?) instead of an `ey` identity token. I use Golang and I found a Google `idtoken` package that returns identity token (as the value of `access_token`). I assume there's an equivalent library from Google for Node.JS. Golang [`idtoken`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/idtoken)

Comment: Here's the Node.JS equivalent of what I'm doing in Golang, it creates an identity token with an `audience` value (required) of a Google Cloud Run service. See: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/main/samples/idtokens-serverless.js

Answer (score 0):

In this example, this code in Java is used to generate a function that creates a JWT, then it signs it by using the private key file, and returns the signed JWT. You could use it in your own code.

```
/**
 * Generates a signed JSON Web Token using a Google API Service Account
 * utilizes com.auth0.jwt.
 */
public static String generateJwt(final String saKeyfile, final String saEmail,
    final String audience, final int expiryLength)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

  Date now = new Date();
  Date expTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(expiryLength));

  // Build the JWT payload
  JWTCreator.Builder token = JWT.create()
      .withIssuedAt(now)
      // Expires after 'expiryLength' seconds
      .withExpiresAt(expTime)
      // Must match 'issuer' in the security configuration in your
      // swagger spec (e.g. service account email)
      .withIssuer(saEmail)
      // Must be either your Endpoints service name, or match the value
      // specified as the 'x-google-audience' in the OpenAPI document
      .withAudience(audience)
      // Subject and email should match the service account's email
      .withSubject(saEmail)
      .withClaim("email", saEmail);

  // Sign the JWT with a service account
  FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(saKeyfile);
  ServiceAccountCredentials cred = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(stream);
  RSAPrivateKey key = (RSAPrivateKey) cred.getPrivateKey();
  Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, key);
  return token.sign(algorithm);
}
```

You can review Google’s documentation of [authentication between services](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication).

EDITED ANSWER

I did an internal consultation with a Google developer to check if there was a piece of node.js code regarding your request.
My suggestion for you is to test using the following information.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/#working-with-id-tokens

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/main/samples/jwt.js

https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-mongodb-auth-jwt/

Comment: Thanks.. I have this code but I could not find a nodejs version of it.. I look at the "google-auth-library" library but no luck